# How to make a variable from database information

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to make a PHP variable equal to an entry in a database. The connection to the database is fine because it is doing other things, but the variable isn't showing up.

Here is my variable declaration:

```
$companyNameRet = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT company_name FROM x6_quote_data WHERE quote_number = '".$getQuote."'") ;
```

The variable is to be used in the "Placeholder" attribute of an input field, effectively to pre-populate a form with data from a database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo $companyNameRet = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT company_name FROM x6_quote_data WHERE quote_number = '".$getQuote."'") ;

Comment: Coudl I suggest sanitising the names of your tables and fields before posting questions to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
$row=$companyNameRet->fetch_assoc();
$myvariable=$row['company_name'];
```

good luck!

For multiple variables, $row will be populated $row['column_name'] for as many column names as you have.  It can get quite confusing if you are decrypting or doing anything fancy with functions so it may be worth assigning aliases:

```
SELECT column1 firstcol,column2 secondcol,column3 thirdcol...
```

In this case, $row would have the aliases as keys:  $row['firstcol'], $row['secondcol'] etc...
Try var_dump($row) to see what you get.  It is most educational to do so.

You can fetch multiple rows by using:

```
while($row=$companyNameRet->fetch_assoc())
    {
    // $row will contain consecutive rows selected from your db.
    }
```

[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) provide a decent tutorial on mysqli basics.  You would do well to read it.

Comment: As I have multiple variables would this still work? How would I go about that?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, you do need to understand that while some of the links I provide are to basic resources, they are very handy for new programmers.  W3Schools provide a series of excellent step by step tutorials that would, if followed have prevented this question being asked at all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get your value right out off the query using raw mysqli API. To do that you have to use some higher level abstraction wrapper, like [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql):

```
$sql = "SELECT company_name FROM x6_quote_data WHERE quote_number = ?s";
$companyNameRet = $db->getOne($sql, $getQuote);
```

Also note that you **should** use **prepared statements**.

Answer (score 0):

your `$getQuote` is place in the `name= "getQuote"` not in the placeholder.

Comment: My mistake, thank you, the variable is in the value attribute now!